# str.contains specific pattern in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

```
COL1

a-b(+)je
a-b(-)neee
a-gd(+)ee 
bb-e(+)bdbd
ad-b(-)ddh
```

and I would like to only get TRUE for row that do contain '(-)' pattern

I tried:

```
df['COL1'].str.contains('(-)')
```

but all row are responding as true because of the `-`in the string

Expected behavior :

```
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

I use that in a code :

```
np.where(df['COL1'].str.contains('(-)'), do something)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `()` are special regex characters you can pass `regex=False`:

```
print (df['COL1'].str.contains('(-)', regex=False))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: COL1, dtype: bool
```

Or escape them by `\`:

```
print (df['COL1'].str.contains('\(-\)'))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: COL1, dtype: bool
```